# The member "Projection" is not recognized

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to set the Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection)" property and I'm getting an error stating that the member "Projection" is not recognized or accessible. Would anyone know what I'm missing?

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
       <Image Source="MyImage.bmp" Width="220" Height="220">
           <Image.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotateX)"  Duration="0:0:2" To="0" />
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
           </Image.Triggers>
       </Image>    
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: So a couple things. What is this, wpf/silverlight/uwp? If it's UWP you should be hitting PlaneProjection and be providing a default for the property to act as the `From` but I didn't think UWP has mousedown as a routed event so I don't think that's it. If it's WPF, I don't think it has Projection ability out of the box without Viewport3d. If it's Silverlight, then you're just missing the default properties set. Share some more info and we'll get you sorted.

Comment: Hi Chris. This is using WPF and maybe Viewport3d is what I'm missing. I'll do a bit of research on it. Thanks for the quick response and direction.